# Ĉu la dua frazo gramatike estas ebla?

Tags: questions

1. Ĉu vi volas esti savata?
2. Ĉu vi volu esti savata?

Kio estas gramatikaj diferencoj inter du frazoj?
Ĉu la dua frazo gramatike estas ebla?

Comment: Bonvolu elekti titolon, kiu estas komprenebla kaj senc-hava eĉ sen la "body" de la demando.

Comment: Bona estas la frazo _**Ĉu vi volas esti savata?**_ Ĉar oni ne povas voli esti jam sav**i**ta. Kaj _volu_ = _devas voli_. Gramatike eblus 1 kaj 2, tamen ne priskribas ion supozeblan, realan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la esperanta `volu` enkondukas [ĝentilan peton](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/vola.html#i-j6t) (aŭ instigon, emigon, ...). Kial? Ĉar oni ne povas fakte ordoni al iu voli ion, ĉiam temas pri ia sugesto.

Ekzemploj Zamenhofaj:

```
Volu montri al mi vian gloron
Volu sidiĝi ...
Volu pardoni min.
```

Oni ankaŭ uzas `bonvolu` en tiuj supraj frazoj.

Kiam temas pri aliaj verboj (ne `voli`), la du strukturoj signifas jenon:

```
Ĉu vi salas surloke?
```

Rekta demando, ĉu oni tion faras aŭ ne.

```
Ĉu vi saltu surloke?
```

Ĝentila peto, eble de kuracisto por scii ĉu genuo doloras aŭ por testi ekvilibron.

Reen al via demando:

```
Ĉu vi volu esti savita?
```

Alia maniero tion diri estus *ĉu vi (bon)volu saviĝi*?. Ĉu tio eblas gramatike? Laŭ mi jes. Ĉu tio kompreneblas? Mi ne certas, pro tio ke la ĉefa verbo estas `voli`. Mi evitus tian frazon.

Comment: Estas parte legeble inter la linioj en la respondo de Eduardo, ke Z uzis esprimojn kun "volu", ekz. "Volu sidiĝi" aŭ "Volu pardoni min". Sed tre rapide aliaj Esperantistoj ekuzis "Bonvolu sid(iĝ)i" resp. "Bonvolu pardoni min".  Nuntempe kelkaj eĉ diras "Bonvole sidu" (legu pli en [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/vola.html). Do kiel Eduardo konstatis: gramatike eblas, komprenebla? ne certe.